# Unable to update JSON field. Shows "JSON parse error - Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes"

Tags: python, json, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am new to Django Rest Framework. I am currently making an API, which will GET the favourite TV shows, and create or update the existing list if more TV shows are made favourite. All of these have a unique account_id. I have to send such a JSON response.

```
{
  "account_id": "15",
  "shows": [
    {
      "show_id": "19"
    },
    {
      "show_id": "86"
    }
  ]
}
```

But when i try to PUT such a JSON response,

```
{
    "account_id": 15,
    "shows": [
    {
        "show_id": "9"
    },
    {
        "show_id": "86"
    }
    ]
}
```

I get the error,

```
{
  "detail": "JSON parse error - Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 2 column 5 (char 6)"
}
```

My models.py is:

```
from django.db import models


class Account(models.Model):
    account_id = models.CharField(max_length=500)


class Show(models.Model):
    show_id = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(Account, related_name='shows')
```

My views.py is:

```
from .models import Show, Account
from showapp.serializers import ShowSerializer, AccountSerializer
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view


class UserList(APIView):

    parser_classes = (JSONParser,)

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        users = Account.objects.all()
        serializer = AccountSerializer(users, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = AccountSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
        user = self.get_object(pk)
        user.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

@api_view(['GET', 'PUT'])
def user_detail(request, account_id):

    try:
        user = Account.objects.get(account_id=account_id)
    except Account.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = AccountSerializer(user)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        serializer = AccountSerializer(user, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

My serializers.py is:

```
class ShowSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Show
        fields = ('show_id',)


class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    shows = ShowSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ('account_id', 'shows')
```

Please Help me out.

Comment: Why do you have two sets of enclosing braces in your PUT content?

Comment: Your second JSON is not valid, you need a key after the first brace { 'key':  { ... } } or remove the first as Daniel suggested

Comment: Okay, I corrected that, but now, "instance expected, got OrderedDict" error occurs

Comment: You should show the full traceback that shows where that error occurred.

Comment: Because `show_id` is not the primary key of your model, I think you need to pass shows like this: `"shows": [1,2,3,4]`, where each number is the id of existing show.

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe it's written like this, try it.**

```
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = AccountSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).